# DOM element not rendering html

Tags: dom, html-table, materialize

I have built an html table that generates dynamically from a data array. It is intended to make a menu of beers on tap in my bar. The array contains the following data: [tap_number, brewery_image, beer_name, price_for_a_pint, price_for_a_pitcher]. Therefore the array dictates that the table generate with 5 columns and 14 rows (with current data).  The image data consists of an html tagged image and similarly the beer_name is tagged `<h3></h3>`.  All the html tagged data is rendering as text.  What have I done wrong?  btw, using Materialize css for basic table styling.  Have tried with bootstrap also - same result. Here's a snippet of the html element that the js generates:

```
<table class = "tabel">
<thead>
<tr>
...has <td>column name</td> X5
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><img src='[url of image]' alt=''></td>
  <td><h3>[Beer_Name]</h3></td>
  <td>$6</td>
  <td>$10</td>
</tr>
...a bunch more rows..
</tbody> 
</table>
.
```

So data positions 1 and 2 should be rendering according to html tag but are just appearing on the page as the text of their html.  All data from the array is passed as textContent.  Should I be using innerHtml?  when I do, nothing at all renders. Cannot figure out what amateur mistake I've made or whether Materialize is screwing me... Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Can you add a working snipet please?

Comment: I figured tnhis out.  I had been using "innerHtml" in the js.  obviously the proper syntax is innerHTML...images are now rendering..

Answer (score 0):

It was an amateur mistake.  was using innerHtml instead of innerHTML....